# Expand numpy array dimension and reshaping

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So i have a numpy array containing:

```
arr =  [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

and when i execute:

```
print(arr.shape)
```

it gives me:

```
(6,)
```

I'm trying to add in the constant value 3

```
 const_val = 3
```

into the dimension of the array so i would obtain:

```
(6,3)
```

First, i tried expanding the dimension of the array by:

```
arr = np.expand_dims(arr, axis = -1)
```

where now:

```
print(arr.shape)
```

returns me:

```
(6,1)
```

However, when i try reshaping the array dimension to replace 1 with the constant value 3,

```
arr = np.reshape(arr, (arr.shape[0], const_val))
```

I get the error saying:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6 into shape (6,3)
```

May i know why did this happen?

Comment: Well how are  you going to `reshape`  an ndarray with 6 values, into one of 18? What values do you want the additional rows to have?

Comment: Reshaping only works if the total amount of elements in the array stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add two empty columns to your array? In that case you can concatenate a matrix of size (6,2):

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]).reshape(6,1)
to_add = np.zeros((6,2))
res = np.concatenate((arr, to_add), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When reshaping from (6,1) to (6,3), you need to 'imput some values' because you go from 6 entries to 18. Do you want the two new columns to be identical to the first one? In that case use [numpy.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) as:

```
arr_6_3 = np.tile(arr, (1,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, the following solution would be the one you need:

```
In [55]: arr =  np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

# our new desired shape
In [56]: new_shape = (6, 3)

# broadcast to `new_shape` and make it writable 
# since `broadcast_to` returns a non-writable and referenced array
In [57]: arr_new = np.array(np.broadcast_to(arr[:, None], new_shape))

# copy the constant value
In [58]: arr_new[:, 1:] = const_val

In [59]: arr_new
Out[59]: 
array([[1, 3, 3],
       [2, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 3, 3],
       [5, 3, 3],
       [6, 3, 3]])
```

---

If, on the other hand, you just want to replicate the same array to the new shape, then use:

```
In [63]: const_val = 3

In [64]: new_shape = (arr.shape[0], const_val)

In [65]: arr_new = np.array(np.broadcast_to(arr[:, None], new_shape))

In [66]: arr_new
Out[66]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6]])

In [67]: arr_new.shape
Out[67]: (6, 3)
```